# IIS7 - Reading File from App Pool

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, permissions, filesystems

**EDIT:**  I made this more confusing than it needed to be.  Forget that this is a Silverlight client.  I have a WCF service hosted in IIS that needs to have access to a file on the local file system.  A consumer of this service will be Silverlight, but I don't think that's important and should have left that out.

I have a Silverlight application where I host a service.  Within this service, I want to read a text file in the root of the C drive (just for testing).  I'm getting an exception thrown that the file could not be found.  I think this is a permissions issue, but I can't figure it out.

I have my app pool Identity set to NetworkService.  I have the .NET Trust Level set to Full (Internal).  I have even gone as far as granting read permissions to the NetworkService user on the text file I am trying to read.

The service needs to have access to the file system.  What is the proper way to do this?

Thanks,

-Scott

Comment: Are you reading the file from the Silverlight app or from the service?

Comment: From the service.  Everything is being done from the server.

Comment: It's the "Silverlight application where I host a service" line that is bothering me.  How are you accessing the service from the Silverlight client?

Comment: Forget about this being a Silverlight application.  Think of this as a simple WCF service that needs to read from a file on the C drivce.  Consumers of this service will be Silverlight and other types of clients as well.  I think I made my question more confussing than I needed to with my reference to Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take out of the equation things that won't be in the equation in real life.  In the real application you aren't going to be reading from C:\.  So its worth thinking about where you will be reading from.

I propose that your file will be in the `App_Data` folder of the website.  So try putting a file there and then accessing it from the service.   You can resolve the App_Data physical file with:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Path\SomeFile.txt");
```

Comment: The reason I was trying to read from the C drive was because I have several reasons for this.  For example, I have to load a native dll usig LoadLibrary() and knew it would be found on the local drive.  However, your post got me to thinking that I could add this dll to my App_Data just like anything else.  I'll give this a try and see if it solves my problems.  Thanks...

Comment: @scott: did you consider putting the all in the web apps bin folder?